# Can I reassign the unused portion of a partition? (OS X/Ubuntu)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

So I just partitioned the hard drive in my MacBook Pro 5,5 and successfully installed Ubuntu (12.04) alongside OS X. During the partition process I guess Disk Utility decided to allocate the majority of the free space (~51GB) even though I specified only 20.

This is really just a learning experience/experimentation and I don't need a lot of space for Ubuntu, so when installing I chose to give it about 20GB (of the 51) to play with. Now I have this remainder of the partition that isn't being used.

My question is can I reassign that space to OS X without disturbing anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ìf the empty partition is between OSX & ubuntu yes you can otherwise it's not possible to attribute this space to OSX - but you can use it as documents space...